Cascading dropdown in Django forms
In the table SchemeMovement, both product and product variant are foreign keys. Also, product is a foreign key in the table product variant. On the screen to make a new entry for SchemeMovement. There is a dropdown to select product. Once it is selected, I want the product variant dropdown to populate accordingly.
The model:
class SchemeMovement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)      
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductMaster, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Product_Id', blank=True, null=True)  
    product_variant = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Product_variant_Id', blank=True, null=True)


class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  
    productid = models.ForeignKey(ProductMaster, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ProductId', blank=True, null=True)  
    variant = models.CharField(db_column='Variant', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True) 

The form:
class SchememovForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = SchemeMovement  
        fields = "__all__"

The html:
<div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
      {{ form.product }}  
    </div>  
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product Variant:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
      {{ form.product_variant }}  
    </div>  
  </div>

With above code, the second dropdown shows all the values from the table product variant. How to show only those related to the product selected in the first dropdown?
